I thought that with parallelism 16 there should be strict distribution across all subtasks
I have a flink application where I use TumblingEventTimeWindows and process function
DataStream<Map<String, Object>> processedEvents = rawEvents
    .keyBy(eventMap -> {
        return calculateKey(eventMap.get("id").toString());
    })
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))
    .allowedLateness(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
    .process(new CustomProcessWindowFunction())
    .setParallelism(16);

calculateKey - always returns a number from 0 to 16. I thought that with parallelism 16 there should be strict distribution across all subtasks, but instead I get 5 idle tasks and several overloaded ones
Tried adding partitioning, changing the hash - none of the approaches gave results
Is there a way to make each subtask process no more than one key?
Thanks!

Flink maps a key to a subtask index using a somewhat complex process that first calculates a "key group" for the key, and then maps that to an operator index (the subtask index). All of this code is inside of the KeyGroupRangeAssignment class.
So your 0...15 key values will get transformed into some number of unique subtask indexes, and this will not be a one-to-one mapping.
You can write code that uses the methods in the KeyGroupRangeAssignment class to generate integer key values that do get mapped to the subtask index. You basically pre-calculate, for each target subtask index, the integer key value that Flink will map to that subtask. Then your calculateKey function just does this lookup to return the appropriate key value.
The pre-calculation just loops over integer values until it finds one that works, so it's not efficient, which is why you want to do this once, versus per-key generation request.
The code looks something like:
    /**
     * Return an integer value that will get partitioned to the target <operatorIndex>, given the workflow's
     * <maxParallelism> (for key groups) and the operator <parallelism>.
     * 
     * @param maxParallelism
     * @param parallelism
     * @param operatorIndex
     * @return Integer suitable for use in a record as the key.
     */
    public static Integer makeKeyForOperatorIndex(int maxParallelism, int parallelism,
            int operatorIndex) {

        for (int i = 0; i < maxParallelism * 2; i++) {
            Integer key = new Integer(i);
            int keyGroup = KeyGroupRangeAssignment.assignToKeyGroup(key, maxParallelism);
            int index = KeyGroupRangeAssignment.computeOperatorIndexForKeyGroup(maxParallelism,
                    parallelism, keyGroup);
            if (index == operatorIndex) {
                return key;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                "Unable to find key for target operator index %d (max parallelism = %d, parallelism = %d",
                operatorIndex, maxParallelism, parallelism));
    }


